# Send email via vb.net web application

Tags: vb.net, email, smtpclient

I'm trying to send a simple plain-text email through my VB.net web application.

I've followed the instructions here:
http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/3.1.1.aspx

But, regardless of what email addresses I use, I keep getting the message "unable to connect to the remote server".

Here is my code

```
'Create the mail message
Dim mail As New MailMessage()

'set the addresses
mail.From = New MailAddress("<email1>")
mail.To.Add("<email2>")

'set the content
mail.Subject = "This is an email"
mail.Body = "this is a sample body"

'send the message
Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("127.0.0.1")
smtp.Send(mail)
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Are you sure that your pc (127.0.0.1, loopback ip) is a SMTP server?

Comment: It's not, so I guess that bit's wrong. What should it say? The smtp server of the mailFrom address?

Comment: Check my answer... :) Anyway, yes, try to use smtp server for maiFrom address in place of 127.0.0.1

Comment: I've managed to get it to work by using gmail and port 25. http://geekswithblogs.net/TakeNote/archive/2007/07/16/113974.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your pc (127.0.0.1, loopback ip) is a SMTP server?
`Dim smtp As New SmtpClient(host)` means that your pc tries to connect to smtp server **host** and use it to send an email.
Check that and you gonna solve your problem...
Just to try: change **127.0.0.1** with the default SMTP server you use in your email software and see what happens...
More: catch the exception (if one is raised) and take note of the message...

Comment: Still the same message "`unable to connect to the remote server`". I'm using `ns1.jasmine.arvixe.com` as the SMTP server.

Comment: Check parameters you use in your email client. Do you use a port different from 25? Do your smtp server require authentication?

Comment: I've just turned off authentication, and set the port to 25. Same error message. (Really appreciating help BTW)

Comment: Let me understand your architecture. Your web app is on a server located somewhere in your provider house, right? If you have "web space", provider gave you (probably) also an email account (or more than one you can choose) and a personal named smtp server. Are you using these params? Sorry, but I need to know something more...

Comment: @Urbycoz: Hey just a $0.02 question, do you think firewall might block port 25?

Comment: @Jeyara. I've tried port 587 too, but that's failing as well.

Comment: @Marco. Yes, you're right. My app is in some webspace, and I'm using my personal named smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this

```
smtp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

and review your firewall settings, maybe the port is closed.

Comment: I'm getting "CredentialCache is not declared" message.