# Sending email in web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, smtpclient

I am trying to send an email after a click of a button. But this is the exception i get

[image]

Is something wrong with my code ? I have already tried to go to my gmail settings and turned on the "Access for less secure apps" , still problem persists.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail 
Imports System.Net

Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page` 

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim mailMessage As New MailMessage("group2@gmail.com", "ndumisosizwe@gmail.com")
        mailMessage.Subject = "Mail Body"
        mailMessage.Body = "This is a test email"
        Dim SmtpClient As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        Dim credentials As New NetworkCredential("group2@gmail.com", "myPasswordHere")
        SmtpClient.Credentials = credentials

        SmtpClient.EnableSsl = True
        SmtpClient.Send(mailMessage)
        MsgBox("Email sent successfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Email Failed !  " & ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

The exception is thrown on the line `SmtpClient.Send(mailMessage)`

Comment: Read [ask], include the actual error text in your question and share your research. It appears your firewall blocks outgoing traffic on port 587.

Comment: use port no 25. also enableSSL is really required?

Comment: That `MsgBox` in a _web_ application looks funny to me. 

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email via vb.net web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865789/send-email-via-vb-net-web-application)

Comment: @Uwe Keim I just wanted a quick way of confirming it was really sent , Testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The port you are using is for TLS according to this [page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en).
The port for SSL (older version) is 465.

Perhaps EnableSsl does not support TLS. You can try with that port.